# Apache rewrite url slug to subdomain

Tags: apache, bitnami

It's my first post there, I couldn't wrap my head around it !

First things first, I'm running a Lightsail instance with a Lamp package using **bitnami**.

My title may seem a bit weird. To better understand it, here's what I'm aiming to do :

1. A user reaches `domain.fr/blog`
2. He's been internally redirected to `blog.domain.fr`
3. The address bar is still showing `domain.fr/blog`

That's something I was able to achieve by using this in the bitnami-ssl.conf under `<VirtualHost default:443>`

```
    ProxyPass /blog http://blog.domain.fr/    
    ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.domain.fr/
```

So when I go to `domain.fr/blog` I can see the blog I'm setting up !

Now I've created myself two problems :

- If I go to `blog.domain.fr` I can access all of the content. Therefore, I have 2 canonical URLs for the same content, which is **really** bad for SEO.
- I can't access `domain.fr/blog/login` for instance...

So I'm asking you guys two questions :

1. How to redirect **properly** `blog.domain.fr` to `domaine.fr/blog`
2. How to make it works **properly** i.e., `/blog/login` not showing 404 (`blog.domain.fr/login` is working)

One more precision : the blog I'm setting up is running using **Laravel** and **Jetstream** ;)

#### Here's what I tried to do :

I've added under the `<Virtual Host *:443>` for the blog vhost this line :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ https://domain.fr/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I end up with the error `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on both `blog.domain.fr` and `domain.fr/blog`

I'm not an Apache expert or whatsoever, please be kind !

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a general approach or not, but when I want to have a subdomain, i just create a virualhost entry into my apache config for that subdomain. you can still point it to the same dir if thats what you want, but by having 2 different entrypoints, you prevent recursion and therefore should not get `too many redirects`

Comment: Thansk @Techno ;)
That's what I've done, I've created an other Virtual Host :)

But I want something that's kinda tricky to access the virtual from a `domain/slug` instead of `subdomain.domain` ;)